# How to add custom headers to request with cljs-http

Tags: http, http-headers, clojurescript

I am using [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http) and I am not able add custom headers into http request. Adding code snippet with request creation:

```
arg {:basic-auth auth 
     :headers {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" " *"
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Origin, X-Custom-Header, Content-Type, Accept"
             "X-Custom-Header" "Custom header"}
    resp (csp/<! (cljs-http/get url arg))
```

Output in chrome console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Request header field X-Custom-Header is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

*Could you please suggest me how to do it ?*

Comment: That's a server issue. Not cljs. Can you replicate the request with CURL and see if it's successful?

Comment: Also, it seems like Chrome wants to see `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` header. Try in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related not to clojurescript, but to server side.

The [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/resources.html) headers were not configured.

While handling requests, server should attach `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Request-Method` headers to response that's permit performing requests for frontend (cljs).